# mcc producing an unresponsive executable

Tags: matlab, executable, mcc

I am trying to compile a Matlab function using the `mcc` function. My function writes a line of text to a file.

```
function hello()
    ofid = fopen('hello.txt','w');
    fprintf(ofid, 'Hello there, this is matlab.\n');
    fclose(ofid);
end
```

It runs as expected when called from the Matlab console. However, when I compile the file to an executable using `mcc`

```
/opt/matlab/matlab2008a/bin/mcc -m hello.m
```

and run it as

```
./hello
```

It seems to run forever and produces no `hello.txt` file. Both the executable as well as the Matlab function files are in the Matlab working directory.

I am unable to see what can be possibly wrong in my use of `mcc`. Please help.

Comment: Does it create the file?

Comment: No, running the executable seems to do nothing. It does not create the file, neither does it terminate.

Comment: When you run the hello(); it does create the file required. Why are you wanting to run it via /opt/matlab/matlab2008a/bin/mcc -m hello.m? just run hello();

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your suggestion. You mean why don't I just call hello() within the Matlab console? Well, the reason for using MCC is that once I get an executable that does the job of the Matlab function, I apparently don't anymore need a Matlab license to run the executable. So it can be helpful when I have a limited number of Matlab licenses for use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you need to setup the MATLAB runtime environment when executing mcc compiled applications.

You'll probably get more mileage the first time by using `deploytool` (from the command line) to compile your hello.m program here.  MATLAB's application builder will produce a run_hello.sh file that you can peruse through to see how they setup their libraries.  Then, to execute your program you would actually call it like this:

./run_hello.sh /Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/

Note: I have just included a generic location for the MATLAB runtime environment, but the actual location will vary depending on your platform and version of MATLAB you built the application with.

Comment: Thanks for your response and telling me about `deploytool`, it seems to almost solve the problem, except that when I build my project using `deploytool`, it seems to place the executable (and the .sh file that you mentioned) inside a folder path: hello/distrib/ . I would ideally like to have the executable in the same folder as the Matlab function. However, that's not a big deal. Is it a better practice to use the run_hello.sh file, like you suggested, rather than directly launching the executable as: ./hello ?

Comment: Is there a way to make `deplytool` output the executable file and/or the run_hello.sh file in the same directory as the main Matlab function? Instead of the folder structure...

Comment: @Pavithran Yes, you can change where the distribution files are created by adjusting the packing settings found with 'deploytool'.  My guess is that it will still be simpler just to copy the files over when you are done.  See this link http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/create-and-install-a-standalone-application-from-matlab-code.html (step 7) for how to change all of this.  The way you are expanding on these follow-on comments I am wondering if you may not be better served writing your method in C and compiling it with 'mex' to run from MATLAB.

Comment: @Pavithran And no, you can't just run the executable as ./hello.  If you edit  the 'run_hello.sh' file, you should see how the run time libraries are loaded and configured before the equivalent call to './hello' is made with the command line arguments passed in (i.e. 'MATLAB_Runtime/v90').  I hope that helps some.

Comment: @information You're right, about not directly running the executable, thanks for telling me about it.

Comment: @information Yes, that is true, I did read a bit (including on the link you mentioned) about changing the output directory of deploytool. Indeed it is not straightforward, so as you suggested, I just copy the run.sh and the executable file to my desirable location.

Comment: @information I guess I was then diverting you with my follow-on comments. My intention is to *not* use Matlab ultimately. Reason is that I want to run a code over many nodes on a cluster and it is not feasible to assume that a lot of licenses exists to support many versions of Matlab.

Comment: Finally, I think the answer has helped me to fix my problem and the executable does run and produce the outputs I expect!

Comment: @Pavithran - Got it.  The licensing piece makes sense for what you want to do (i.e. and not mex compilation).  One problem you may still have however is that the entire run time library needs to be loaded each time you run your compiled application.  That is, it will take roughly the same amount of time before your program to start (from the moment you call it or click on the .exe) as it does to open up MATLAB.  So if you have a cluster and a bunch of nodes and are hoping to call your compiled program multiple times like a function, you will have a serious time tradeoff.

Comment: @information, Thanks for that useful note. That could be the most appropriate reason for my observation of longer that expected runtime. I am still a newbie to the Matlab compiler, but perhaps there is no real workaround to this problem.